# How to read a date value in YYYYMM format using substring in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

In my table customer_records there is a column StartDate having value in `DDMMYYYYHHMMSS` format (column datatype is VARCHAR).
I want to extract the data from the table group by the date in `YYYYMM` format.

I have below working query: which will extract the data in `MMYYYY` format.

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a , 8 ) */
          NVL (SUBSTR (StartDate, 3, 6), 'Total') "Year-Month",Started",
         TO_CHAR (COUNT (1), '999,999,999') "Customer Count",
         TO_CHAR (
              SUM (Usage)/60,
            '999,999,999')`enter code here`
            "Duration (M)"
    FROM customer_records a
   WHERE type='NEW'
          and customer_status=0 
GROUP BY ROLLUP (to_date(SUBSTR (StartDate, 3, 6),'MMYYYY'), 'Total')
ORDER BY 1;
```

but I want the Date format to come in `YYYYMM` format.
I have tried the following options. but not working,

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a , 8 ) */
        NVL (to_date(SUBSTR (StartDate, 3, 6),'MMYYYY'), 'Total') "Month Started",
         TO_CHAR (COUNT (1), '999,999,999') "Customer Count",
         TO_CHAR (
              SUM (Usage)/60,
            '999,999,999')
            "Duration (M)"
    FROM customer_records a
   WHERE type='NEW'
          and customer_status=0 
GROUP BY ROLLUP (to_date(SUBSTR (StartDate, 3, 6),'MMYYYY'), 'Total')
ORDER BY 1;
```

can somebody please help me to edit above query to fetch the data in `YYYYMM` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If given startdate is in date format then below one will works well.

Update: As you have mentioned in the comments it is not in datw format then you first convert it into date format then required YYYYMM format by using to_char function

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(a , 8 ) */
            NVL ( to_CHAR(to_date(substr(StartDate, 1,8),'DDMMYYYY'),'YYYYMM'),'Total') "Month Started",
             TO_CHAR (COUNT (1), '999,999,999') "Customer Count",
             TO_CHAR (
                  SUM (Usage)/60,
                '999,999,999')
                "Duration (M)"
        FROM customer_records a
       WHERE type='NEW'
              and customer_status=0 
    GROUP BY ROLLUP (to_CHAR(to_date(substr(StartDate, 1,8),'DDMMYYYY'),'YYYYMM'))
    ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: need to take substr of Startdate as its format is DDMMYYYYHHMMSS.

Comment: no need to take substring if that date is in date format

Comment: thanks for the answer. but failing with below error : 01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.

Comment: a correction, the coulumn Data type is VARCHAR. not date. appologies

Comment: bad luck. failing with below error : ORA-01810: format code appears twice
01810. 00000 -  "format code appears twice"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: last try... I have again updated the answer with substr function to take first 8 chars.. try with that n let me know any luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146599/discussion-between-rams-and-msn).

Answer (score -1):

you can try:::

```
select TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(StartDate, 'MM/YYYY'), 'MM/YYYY') mmyyyyFormatDate from customer_records ;  --get the date in mm/yyyy format
```